# How to use Two Tables with Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a report in Crystal Reports.  I would like to use two tables.  I set up the data table like below.  In the report designer, I select both the customer and the trans tables.  I designed my report but nothing shows up (empty report).  I take away the customer table in the report designer and, voila, data appears.  I really need the customer data, too, though.  I know I can accomplish this using a view however I am trying to avoid the overhead of that because I'm going to have dozens upon dozens of reports and I don't want to have a view for each.

```
    public void ConfigureCrystalReports()
    {
        Shared_Items.UtilitiesClass ru = new UtilitiesClass();
        string cs = ru.getConnectionString();

        string sql = "select a.*, b.cust_name from trans a left outer join customer b on a.customer = b.customer  where a.customer  like '"+customerFinder+"'";

        SqlConnection cx = new SqlConnection(cs);
        cx.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter ta = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cx);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ta.Fill(ds);

        // declare the report
        ControlsTransactionSummaryBycustomer report = new ControlsTransactionSummaryBycustomer();

        report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

        // Binding the crystalReportViewer with our report object. 
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
        crystalReportViewer1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I assume you verified you get the correct raw data when running the query with both tables?

Comment: I cannot get any data when I use two tables.  When I remove the customer table, I get all the transactions and it works properly.  As soon as I add back in the customer table, I get nada.

Comment: If the query doesn't return data, then you need to focus on that first before trying to display it in the report. What do the tables look like?

Comment: The tables are full of data.  It just doesn't display on the report.  I gave up and made a view and it works fine.  I wish I could have figured it out because I don't want my database filled with views but it looks like that's how it's going to be!